# Json response in javascript is not looping correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JsonResponse which looks like this:

```
    [{"pk": 1, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1], "group_id": "spott", "group_name": "spott"}, "model": "grouping"},
{"pk": 2, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1, 2], "group_id": "spottalle", "group_name": "spott alle"}, "model": "grouping"}]
```

I have tried to access the data like this:

```
    for (var key in data) {
            console.log(key)
            console.log(data[key]);
        }
```

The Response is every letter not every object. Which is a bit weird, after looking through the answers on stackoverflow, i tried the other ways as well but always get the same result.

The Result should be the group_name and the group_id. Can anyone help me with that? Thank you in advance

Comment: It is an array...use `for-loop...` instead of `for-in..` make sure you are ot iterating `JSON`...You must have `Object/Array`

Comment: @RayonDabre you mean like that?   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var obj = data[i];

       console.log(obj.id);
   }. That didn't work :(

Comment: __Yes__, I doubt it is `object/array`...Check `typeof data`

Comment: @RayonDabre typof data says its a string :O

Comment: Then you must parse it before looping..`JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: @RayonDabre thank you that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this is an array, so you can simply loop it using a classic for loop, this is an exmaple snippet:

```
    var data = [{"pk": 1, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1], "group_id": "spott", "group_name": "spott"}, "model": "grouping"},
            {"pk": 2, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1, 2], "group_id": "spottalle", "group_name": "spott alle"}, "model": "grouping"}];

            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
               console.log(data[i]); //You will get an object
               console.log(data[i].pk);
            }
```

In each iteration you will get an object and then you can access its properties.

**EDIT:**

It dependes on the type of `data` here, if it's a `string` like you mentioned in comments, you should parse it using `JSON.parse(data);` first then you can loop throught it.

Otherwise if it is an `array` you will just need to directly loop throught its elements.

Comment: It is `JSON` not `Array`..Question says _The Response is every letter not every object_

Comment: Yes you are right about it, but it can be looped using the for loop.

Comment: from the given input (json) of the OP you will get objects when you loop, you can test my snippet and you will see it working.

Comment: Go through the comments and you will get to know..You have to make out that it is `JSON` from _The Response is every letter not every object_

Comment: Yes indeed you are right as it is a string in the OP, for my example I used the given input which is an array as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Try using $.each instead of for loop :

Try this :

```
var object = [{"pk": 1, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com","locations": [1], "group_id": "spott", "group_name": "spott"}, "model": "grouping"},
{"pk": 2, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1, 2], "group_id": "spottalle", "group_name": "spott alle"}, "model": "grouping"}];

$.each(object, function(index, singleObject) {
   console.log("Single Object :%O",singleObject);
});
```

In console you will get object properly.

For Fiddle Link Click Here : [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8ynch623/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
<script>
var object =  [{"pk": 1, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1], "group_id": "spott", "group_name": "spott"}, "model": "grouping"},
{"pk": 2, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1, 2], "group_id": "spottalle", "group_name": "spott alle"}, "model": "grouping"}];

for(var i=0; i<object.length; i++){
    console.log(object[i].pk);
    console.log(object[i].fields.email);
    console.log(object[i].fields.group_id);
}


</script>
```

Please let me know if it is not expected output.

Answer (score 0):

response is in encoded manner,for access you want to decode response.

```
var x=[{"pk": 1, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1], "group_id": "spott", "group_name": "spott"}, "model": "grouping"},{"pk": 2, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1, 2], "group_id": "spottalle", "group_name": "spott alle"}, "model": "grouping"}]; 

var object=JSON.parse(x);//you will get an object then you can find what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the bellow simple instruction :

```
var array=[{"pk": 1, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1], "group_id": "spott", "group_name": "spott"}, "model": "grouping"},
{"pk": 2, "fields": {"email": "info@spott.com", "locations": [1, 2], "group_id": "spottalle", "group_name": "spott alle"}, "model": "grouping"}];

array.forEach(function(obj){
 //to get the current object 
  console.log(obj)
 // to access to the attribute of the current object 
// example 
console.log(obj.fields.email)

});
```